# Get the perl string calculation result

Tags: string, perl

If one string is expressed like below
$str = "5+2-1";
I'd like to get the calculation result from that string.
How do I convert to scalar to compute this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to do this:

```
print eval('5+2-1');
```

but it's not safe:

```
print eval('print "You are hacked"');
```

You need to check string before `eval` it.
Also you can use [Math::Expression](http://search.cpan.org/~addw/Math-Expression-1.21/Expression.pm) module or many other modules from cpan:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::Expression;

my $env = Math::Expression->new;

my $res = $env->Parse( '5+2-1' );

# my $res = $env->Parse( 'print you are hacked' );  # no math expression here

print $env->Eval( $res );
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are sure the string does not contain any malicious code you can use eval to treat the content of it as perl code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "5+2-1";

print eval($string);
#print 6
```